# Univariate time-series data with 30 minutes interval - Which algorithm to use for forecasting?

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting

I am working on a case study to predict # of calls for next 30 days.

The data is at 30 minutes interval and start from 7 am to 23:30 PM (So 34 observations in a day).

I have two questions:

What would be the frequency ?

Which Machine Learning algorithm would be the best to predict next 30 days?

I tried LSTM, however it takes much longer just to complete 25 epochs.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities): there will be pattern within days, but weekdays will very likely also differ from weekends. So your frequencies will be both 34 (the length of intra-daily cycles) and 7*34=238 (the length of intra-weekly cycles). You may also have other periodicities, like monthly or yearly ones, but these will likely be the dominant ones.

[The tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) contains pointers to useful forecasting algorithms and implementations in R (nothing in Python that I am aware of, sorry).